# Checkbox list, alphabetically ordered in topdown columns

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I'm trying to display my list of checkboxes so that the alphabetical order is vertical instead of horizontal.  Obviously things are fine when the container in the fiddle is dragged to only single column width, but from 2 columns onwards the checkbox order runs horizontally.  I can't seem to apply any of the previous related posts to this (using display:block, float: left, etc) but nothing works and it's doing my head in!  Any help much appreciated.  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rub5rc8x/

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

<div class="CountryListBoxClass_prodn">
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN40" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN100" value="Bulgaria" />Bulgaria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN191" value="Croatia" />Croatia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN208" value="Denmark" />Denmark</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN233" value="Estonia" />Estonia</label>
 <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN276" value="Germany" />Germany</label>
 <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN348" value="Hungary" />Hungary</label>
 <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN372" value="Ireland" />Ireland</label>
 <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN428" value="Latvia" />Latvia</label>
 <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN470" value="Malta" />Malta</label>
</div>
```

.

```
.CountryListBoxClass_prodn label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 213px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px 7px 2px 0px;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn input {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  Padding: 10px 0px 0px 5px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Just use CSS columns …https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts -> http://jsfiddle.net/rub5rc8x/1/

Comment: remove `display: inline-block` from .CountryListBoxClass_prodn label { } (?)

Comment: If you need to support < ie11, try the jQuery columnizer plugin. https://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Comment: @CBroe CSS columns was exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: @CBroe I've just noticed that if the width of the fiddle container is expanded to wider than 2 columns, the checkbox order goes back to horizontal.  I suppose this makes sense with a 2 column count.  Is there are way to preserve the order across >2 columns without fixing the column count?

Comment: Make the items wider, or limit the width of the container element …?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I actually want to allow >2 columns if the User drags the container width.

Comment: OK, I've worked out that I can do this using CSS 'column-width' instead of 'column-count'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`flex`** css and their order can be set by some jQuery logic as below

```js
var n = $('.myEuropeCountries').length;
for (i = 1; i <= (n / 2).toFixed(); i++) {
  $('.myEuropeCountries:nth-child(' + i + ')').css('order', (2 * i - 1))
}
for (i = (n / 2 + 1).toFixed(); i <= n; i++) {
  $('.myEuropeCountries:nth-child(' + i + ')').css('order', (2 * i - n - (n % 2)))
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn label {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 49%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0.5%;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn input {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.CountryListBoxClass_prodn {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="CountryListBoxClass_prodn">
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN40" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN100" value="Bulgaria" />Bulgaria</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN191" value="Croatia" />Croatia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN208" value="Denmark" />Denmark</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN233" value="Estonia" />Estonia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN276" value="Germany" />Germany</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN348" value="Hungary" />Hungary</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN372" value="Ireland" />Ireland</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN428" value="Latvia" />Latvia</label>
  <label class="myEuropeCountries">
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN470" value="Malta" />Malta</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works well with 2 columns, but as with 'column-count:2', the alphabetical ordering goes back to horizontal once the width container is dragged wider and more columns are created.